# Get nearest points by sindex at large data

Tags: geopandas, proximity

I have cities and roads of a large region. I want to get distance of the cities by roads that connect them. However, coordinates of cities are not exactly on the roads so I cannot implement intersection. I spatial indexed the roads in order to get the nearest_point faster.

```
# Build the spatial index on roads
road_sindex = ME_road.sindex

city_approx_list = []

for city in ME_city.itertuples():
    best_approx = Point()  # Initialize the best approximation point
    min_distance = float('inf')  # Initialize the minimum distance

    # Use spatial indexing to find nearby roads
    possible_matches_index = list(road_sindex.intersection(city.geometry.bounds))
    possible_matches = ME_road.iloc[possible_matches_index]

    for road in possible_matches.itertuples():
        near_sample = nearest_points(city.geometry, road.geometry)
        if near_sample[0].distance(near_sample[1]) < min_distance:
            best_approx = near_sample[1]
            min_distance = near_sample[0].distance(near_sample[1])

    city_approx_list.append({'city': f"{city.ascii_name}", 'geometry': best_approx})

# Create a GeoDataFrame from the list
city_approx_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(city_approx_list, geometry='geometry', crs=ME_city.crs)
```

`city_approx_gdf` has some cities of which geometries are "EMPTY POINTS" although cities all have geometries.

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can use sjoin_nearest which uses indexing by default, so no need to create them manually. This finishes in about 3 s. for 158000 lines and 2600 points.

```
import geopandas as gpd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from shapely.ops import nearest_points
from shapely import LineString

con = create_engine("postgresql://postgres@localhost/data")
roads = gpd.read_postgis(sql="select id, geom from lmv.ok_vl_riks", con=con)
cities = gpd.read_postgis(sql="select id, geom from lmv.ok_ns_riks", con=con)
print(roads.shape[0], cities.shape[0])
#158197 2644

roads["roadgeom"] = roads.geometry
sj = gpd.sjoin_nearest(left_df=cities, right_df=roads, 
                       distance_col="distance", max_distance=20000, how="left")

#Make sure there's a road within max_distance of each city
#print(sj.id_right.isnull().any())
#False #Yes there is. If if was True max_distance would need to be higher

#If there's multiple roads within max_distance each point will be duplicated
#print(sj.id_left.duplicated().any())
#True #Yes, duplicates

sj = sj.sort_values(by=["id_left","distance"]) #Sort from nearest distance to farthest
sj = sj.drop_duplicates(subset="id_left", keep="first") #Keep nearest

sj[["citypoint", "roadpoint"]] = sj.apply(lambda x: nearest_points(x.geom, x.roadgeom), 
                                          axis=1, result_type="expand")
sj["connection_line"] = sj.apply(lambda x: LineString([x.citypoint, x.roadpoint]), axis=1)

sj.set_geometry("connection_line")[["connection_line"]].set_crs(roads.crs).to_file(r"/home/bera/Desktop/GIStest/connection_line.gpkg")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It was a great hint that sjoin_nearest uses indexing.

Comment: If it solved your problem [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)